# Who is going to handle flags without Pro Tempore Moderators?

Tags: support, flagging, moderation

We don't yet have Pro Tempore Moderators, so who is going to handle the flags?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We (Stack Exchange) will handle what the community can't while we look for pro-tem moderators. This mostly includes:

- Approving suggested edits, since it will be a little while before anyone has the rep to do so
- Handling spam or abuse
- Closing of *wildly* problematic questions
- Removing answers that were *clearly* meant as follow up chatter
- Cleaning up comments as needed

For the most part, we want *you* to handle as much as you can; we're just here to make sure things don't go unhandled.